# How can I insert Foreign Key(FK) in starUML ER diagram?

Tags: foreign-keys, entity-relationship, staruml

I'm working on a ER diagram in starUML but can't find a Foriegn Key option in it. I've looked through various setting in the application but couldn't find it. Is they a way to insert? Also, I've seen images using FK in starUML but couldn't find out how. Can someone help me out?

[image: I]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select a column in the table and look at the properties on the right side of the editor.
[image: En esta parte se encuentra]